# The undo feature in the Eclipse ADT is not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I download the Eclipse with the ADT for developing the Android project.

However, there is one really annoying problem.

The undo features is not working so I can't use the undo function to roll back to my previous codes...

On the top panel, Edit > Undo/Redo feature is always grey out(disabled).

I have went online and searched for some possible solution but in vain.

I tried to check out the Undo history size and set it to 2000, however, still not working.

My enviroment is:

- Linuxmint 15 x64
- Android Developer Tools, Build: v22.3.0-887826
- Eclipse Platform, Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7

Does anyone know how to fix this issue ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Ctrl + z, Ctrl + Shift + Z if you fail you can change settings Window>Preferences>General>Keys here redo and undo Change

Comment: Thanks. But it does not has do with the key shortcut.
It looks like a my system went crazy temporarily.
After I restart the system, everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Got solved. It looks like my system went crazy temporarily. After I restart the system, everything goes fine.